# How to get bot's username in aiogram?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, telegram, telegram-bot, aiogram

For the sake of studying the capabilities of the Telegram API, the question arose, how to get the @username of a bot in a telegram using **aiogram**?

I tried `username = bot.get_me().username` but gives the following error:
`AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'username'`
How can this be fixed?

Comment: You should await the `get_me` method. Try: `username = (await bot.get_me()).username`

Comment: bot.get_me() is not an async function

Comment: Error tells that it returns a coroutine. What else it is if not an async function?

Comment: When I try `username = (await bot.get_me()).username` it looks like this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1n-KkcmamiMCCCUwrSSislgriqDtjo3aW/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The link you have provided does not have public access.

Comment: Sorry, I'll try to be more careful. Now it has public access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the username of the bot by calling [`get_me`](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/telegram/bot.html?highlight=get_me#aiogram.bot.bot.Bot.get_me) on the `Bot` object.

The returned objects hold the `username` you are looking for.

---

Example code:

```py
async def main():
    bot = Bot(token='859163076:AAEjLUL8Lx67blablalblalblalbal')
    info = await bot.get_me();
    name = info.username

    print(name) 

asyncio.run(main())
```

Answer (score 1):

Its because u tryna get attribute of coro, not coro returned object

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34574807)